# scrollTop().stop() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a wordpress site and I need to somehow disable the `scrollTop()` function globally that is coming from a plugin because that shoots it off the screen. I can't modify the source code of the plugin in case an update occurs.

I'm attempting to do this by just adding this line into a click event:

`$("html, body").scrollTop().stop();`

my expectation is that the animation that comes from the other plugin gets stopped but I get

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollTop(...).stop is not a function

Why would that not be a function? Can you not use `stop()` on scrollTop? Very confused. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `scrollTop` returns a number. What do you expect `.stop()` to do?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you would expect `.stop()` to be a function here.  Have you looked up what `.scrollTop()` does?  https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop  Or how to use `.stop()`?  https://api.jquery.com/stop

Comment: I suspect what you really want to do is disable `scrollTo()`, not `scrollTop()`.

Comment: @Barmar ohhhhhh

Answer (score 2):

The function that's used to scroll the window is `scrollTo()`. `scrollTop()` just returns the current scoll position.

You can redefine it to do nothing with:

```
window.scrollTo = function() {};
```

If you want to be able to re-enable it, you can save the value first:

```
window.saveScrollTo = window.scrollTo;
```

Then later you can restore it with:

```
window.scrollTo = window.saveScrollTo;
```